# java 8: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath

Tags: xml, java-8, jaxb

I am using Java 8. I am migrating a very old application from WebLogic to JBoss EAP 7.4, and I'm incurring in the error when I try to print a PDF:

```
Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath
```

This error seems to be caused by `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.ContextFactory` so I added com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-osgi, javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api and com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl, I kept getting missing classes and I added various jaxb dependency  combinations but I kept having issues like `NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/xml/bind/ImplementationRegistry`.

I got stuck here.

So I tried to switch to a more modern approach and follow [this guide](https://www.javaguides.net/2020/01/jaxb-how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-xml.html) but now I have this error: `class [Ljava.lang.Object; nor any of its super class is known to this context.`

This is probably because the object I'm trying to marshall is of the class Object so I couldn't use the annotation @XmlRootElement on it.

Basically my print service class is pretty generic and needs to be used in different parts of the application. It looks like this:

```
Object bean = createBean(request, httpServlet);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Object.class);
Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
m.marshal(bean, fos);
```

And the method createBean generated an Object[] array with a series of objects in it.

How can I generate this PDF? Is there a way to annotate Object with @XmlRootElement?